# Add extended property to tables and columns using Entity Framework Code First

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first-mapping

**I am using Entity Framework Code First to design my database.**

I am wondered if there is a way to add extended property to my tables and columns using entity framework, so I can use my code docs in database.

[image]

That would be great.

Comment: What is "extended property"?

Comment: @Klamsi I attached picture.

Comment: Ah a Sql Server specific issue. I'm out ;)

Comment: No, none other than calling `sys.sp_addextendedproperty` as SQL.